# Implement custom ASP.NET Identity using existing database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I would like to customize ASP.NET Identity to work with an external database.

The default schema looks like that:

[image]

The part that bothers me, is the User table.

I succeeded to move the database to SQL Server Express and then I tried to modify the Table and deleted some columns.

When I tried to build and run the project I got multiple errors demanding for the columns I deleted and there is no mention to them in the code (Just new MVC project).

I would like that it will look more like this:

[image]

Of course I'll want to add some more table but that we'll be after the Users part will be complete.

So, is there some kind of tutorial that can explain how to customize Identity to my needs ?

Or anything help that can help me build stable users system.

Comment: Removing columns and features generally does not work with the default Identity. You would have to set up your own user store and things to make sure everything works. I personally don’t think that is worth the hassle. You can just use the default schema, add your two properties to the ApplicationUser, and then live with the rest of the default – just ignore those features you are not interested in.

Comment: I thought about that option, but I really don't want to work messy and it'll be part of the learning.